# how to iter through whole html table and convert to json data?

Tags: python, json, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am working on python3,I already converted html table to json object but its not iterating throught whole table just giving  output of first row.
 this is my code:

```
html_source= """<div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" 
rules="all" border="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1" 
style="background-color:White;border-color:#3366CC;border- 
width:2px;border-style:Solid;font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;border- 
collapse:collapse;">
<tr style="color:#CCCCFF;background-color:#003399;font-weight:bold;">
<th scope="col">AC NO</th><th scope="col">PART NO</th><th 
 scope="col">SR NO</th><th scope="col">Voter Name</th><th 
scope="col">ID CARD NO</th><th scope="col">GENDER</th><th 
scope="col">AGE</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp; 
</th>
</tr><tr style="color:#003399;background-color:White;">
<td>211</td><td>396</td><td>294</td><td>name 1</td><td>UVP7645302</td> 
<td>M</td><td>28</td><td><input type="button" value="Polling Station 
Address"onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1&#39;,&#39;View Details$0&#39;)" style="width:150px;" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Family" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1& 
#39;,&#39;Family$0&#39;)" /></td>
</tr><th scope="col">AC NO</th><th scope="col">PART NO</th><th 
scope="col">SR NO</th><th scope="col">Voter Name</th><th 
 scope="col">ID CARD NO</th><th scope="col">GENDER</th><th 
 scope="col">AGE</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp; 
</th>
</tr><tr style="color:#003399;background-color:White;">
<td>211</td><td>396</td><td>295</td><td>name 2</td><td>UVP7645302</td> 
<td>M</td><td>28</td><td><input type="button" value="Polling Station>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source,'html.parser')


for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    keys = [th.get_text(strip=True)for th in table.find_all('th')]
    values = [td.get_text(strip=True)for td in table.find_all('td')]
    d = dict(zip(keys,values))
    #print(d)
    mydict =  (json.dumps(d))

empty = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if not v}
for k in empty:
del d[k]
print(json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False))
```

my expected output:

> {"AC NO": "211", "PART NO": "396", "SR NO": "294", "Voter Name": "name 1",
>   "ID CARD NO": "UVP7645302", "GENDER": "M", "AGE": "28"},{"AC
>   NO": "211", "PART NO": "396", "SR NO": "294", "Voter Name": "name 2",
>   "ID CARD NO": "UVP7645302", "GENDER": "M", "AGE": "28"}

actual output :

> {"AC NO": "211", "PART NO": "396", "SR NO": "294", "Voter Name": "name
>   1", "ID CARD NO": "UVP7645302", "GENDER": "M", "AGE": "28"}

Comment: Hi, it would help greatly if you could format the HTML string to be more readible, as well as the expected and actual output. Since they're quite long, it's difficult to see exactly what's missing

Comment: One problem is that you dont collect the dict's you find. Declare a list to hold the data and append dicts to the list. In the specific case of your HTML there is only one table so it does not make a real difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas` library :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

html_source= """<div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" 
rules="all" border="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1" 
style="background-color:White;border-color:#3366CC;border- 
width:2px;border-style:Solid;font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;border- 
collapse:collapse;">
<tr style="color:#CCCCFF;background-color:#003399;font-weight:bold;">
<th scope="col">AC NO</th><th scope="col">PART NO</th><th 
 scope="col">SR NO</th><th scope="col">Voter Name</th><th 
scope="col">ID CARD NO</th><th scope="col">GENDER</th><th 
scope="col">AGE</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp; 
</th>
</tr><tr style="color:#003399;background-color:White;">
<td>211</td><td>396</td><td>294</td><td>name 1</td><td>UVP7645302</td> 
<td>M</td><td>28</td><td><input type="button" value="Polling Station 
Address"onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1&#39;,&#39;View Details$0&#39;)" style="width:150px;" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Family" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1& 
#39;,&#39;Family$0&#39;)" /></td>
</tr><th scope="col">AC NO</th><th scope="col">PART NO</th><th 
scope="col">SR NO</th><th scope="col">Voter Name</th><th 
 scope="col">ID CARD NO</th><th scope="col">GENDER</th><th 
 scope="col">AGE</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp; 
</th>
</tr><tr style="color:#003399;background-color:White;">
<td>211</td><td>396</td><td>295</td><td>name 2</td><td>UVP7645302</td> 
<td>M</td><td>28</td><td><input type="button" value="Polling Station>"""

table = pd.read_html(html_source)[0]
print(table.to_dict('records'))
```

O/P:

```
[{'AC NO': 211, 'PART NO': 396, 'SR NO': 294, 'Voter Name': 'name 1', 'ID CARD NO': 'UVP7645302', 'GENDER': 'M', 'AGE': 28, 'Unnamed: 7': nan, 'Unnamed: 8': nan}, {'AC NO': 211, 'PART NO': 396, 'SR NO': 295, 'Voter Name': 'name 2', 'ID CARD NO': 'UVP7645302', 'GENDER': 'M', 'AGE': 28, 'Unnamed: 7': nan, 'Unnamed: 8': nan}]
```

If you want to drop `Unnamed` from the dictionary, add this line before `print(table.to_dict('records'))`  statement

```
table = table.loc[:,~table.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]
```

O/P:

```
[{'AC NO': 211, 'PART NO': 396, 'SR NO': 294, 'Voter Name': 'name 1', 'ID CARD NO': 'UVP7645302', 'GENDER': 'M', 'AGE': 28}, {'AC NO': 211, 'PART NO': 396, 'SR NO': 295, 'Voter Name': 'name 2', 'ID CARD NO': 'UVP7645302', 'GENDER': 'M', 'AGE': 28}]
```